# How can I set default authors for new Cargo projects?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustup

When creating a new project with `cargo new`, I would like to have the Cargo.toml file automatically include a predefined `authors` field.

The [Rust book said](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.52.1/book/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html#creating-a-project-with-cargo):

> The next four lines set the configuration information Cargo needs to compile your program: the name, the version, who wrote it, and the edition of Rust to use. ***Cargo gets your name and email information from your environment***, so if that information is not correct, fix the information now and then save the file.

It was pretty vague, so I searched about it. First I tried adding `CARGO_NAME` and `CARGO_EMAIL` to my environment variables. Didn't work.

Then I tried adding the variables `name` and `email` in the field `[cargo-new]`, on the `.cargo/config.toml` config file and learned it is deprecated.

Are there any other ways to do this? Did I do something wrong?

```
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

authors = ["foo <bar@gmail.com>"] # Add this line automatically

[dependencies]
```

I'm using `rustup` with the `nightly` toolchain on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The behaviour was changed in [RFC 3052](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/3052-optional-authors-field.md), implemented in Cargo 1.53. From the RFC:

> cargo init will stop pre-populating the field when running the
> command, and it will not include the field at all in the default
> Cargo.toml. Crate authors will still be able to manually include the
> field before publishing if they so choose.

It turned out that the `authors` list in a crate's manifest created more problems than it solved, because the manifest is immutable, while the authors of a crate are not.

So as of today, there is no way to automatically add `authors` on a new cargo project.

Comment: So it is optional to add the authors field when publishing a project?

Comment: If RFC 3052 is in production on crates.io, which it should, then yes.

Comment: How would one go about updating "the book" to include this information (that the authors field is no longer automatically populated and no longer necessary)?  I am just starting to read the book and found that confusing also (and I've been programming since 1972 and spent a day looking for how to set an environment variable or command line option or something to populate that field to my liking).

Comment: File an issue with [the repo](https://github.com/rust-lang/book)